# Match regex for given statement

Tags: regex

I want to write regex for the following statement and match the bolded characters "The following strings must be matched
**xyz.90001DUS.annotations** and **xyz.765896DUS.courses**".

I tried to write one using regex but it is not matching above strings, can someone please help me?

It should match whole of bolded strings, this is the only criteria.

```
^xyz.([0-9])?DUS.annotations(.*)?\.annotations$
```

Comment: `\bxyz\.[0-9]+DUS\.(?:annotations|courses)\b`? Or maybe `\bxyz\.[0-9]+DUS\.\w+`? Please [edit] the question and explain the criteria for matching those strings.

Comment: Hi @41686d6564, above answer did work, only criteria I had was match whole of bolded strings! Submit it as answer plz

Comment: Is that PostgreSQL? I removed the `~*` from the regex line in your question. If it is, `\b` is not used in that regex flavor.

Comment: Useful web site for testing out regexes: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your `^xyz.([0-9])?DUS.annotations(.*)?\.annotations$` cannot match the strings inside a longer string due to anchors, `^` and `$`. Besides, `.` matches any char other than line break chars,  `([0-9])?` matches a single optional digit (while you have five in `90001`). The `(.*)?\.annotations` part would match any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible consuming chars up to the last occurrence of `.annotations`.

What you can use is

```
xyz\.\d+DUS\.\w+
```

Or, with word boundaries:

```
\bxyz\.\d+DUS\.\w+        <<< In most NFA regex flavors
\yxyz\.\d+DUS\.\w+        <<< In PostgreSQL, Tcl
\mxyz\.\d+DUS\.\w+        <<< R (TRE), Tcl
\<xyz\.\d+DUS\.\w+        <<< GNU word boundary
[[:<:]]xyz\.\d+DUS\.\w+   <<< POSIX word boundary
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhX7lV/1). You do not need a word boundary after `\w+`, there is always a word boundary after the trailing `\w+` in any regex pattern.

*Details*:

- `xyz\.` - `xyz.`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `DUS\.` - `DUS.`
- `\w+` - one or more word chars.